# Can you change the name of the Django admin 'is_staff' flag?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to rename the "`is_staff`" flag to "`is_volunteer`" to better model the use-cases of our system. The function of this flag should stay exactly the same: only users with `is_volunteer = True` can access the admin interface.

I haven't dug through the `django.contrib.auth` library to determine how rigid the model is, but I'm curious if anyone has done this before.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a group `is_volunteer` and assign various permissions to this group.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. The [`is_staff` flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) controls who has access to the admin site and is not a permissions group. I'm looking to modify that flag, not create a group.

Comment: Just wondering what were your solution @nicholaspoz , Can you share how you solved that ?

Comment: I have exactly the same question since I don't want to go the permissions route yet nor do I want a custom user model either: I think will simply massage all of my JSON only inputs and outputs is_staff <=> is_volunteer or whatever in my case with two functions for now..